# App crashes when performing unwind

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, segue, unrecognized-selector

**What I'm trying to perform**

- A programmatic unwind from Screen C back to Screen A (normally A->B->C)

---

**What I've done**

- I've created the function `- (IBAction)unwindToScreenA:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {`
   in Screen A's `.m` and its definition in `.h` file.
- I've created an manual unwind in Screen C by CTRL-Dragging from Owner Icon to Escape Icon (unwind segue exists, but not tied to any button)
- I've given the unwind a name, and then in the code I perform `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromCtoA" sender:self];`
- In other words, I think I've strictly done what's needed for this task. I did have it working before, but something else I changed must have broken it, and I can't trace the error.

---

**The error I have**

```
2014-02-06 13:28:28.899 PrototypeApp2[2885:60b] -[DMSScreenCViewController tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e7ff60

2014-02-06 13:28:28.902 PrototypeApp2[2885:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

reason: '-[DMSScreenCViewController tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e7ff60'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x2ddf7f4b 0x382386af 0x2ddfb8e7 0x2ddfa1cb 0x2dd494d8 0xc966d 0x30ae6d63 0xca34f 0x30782dcd 0x30782c15 0x306878bb


0x3073af7b 0x305eafb9 0x305631f3 0x2ddc31cd 0x2ddc0b71 0x2ddc0eb3 0x2dd2bc27 0x2dd2ba0b 0x32a52283 0x305cf049 0xc80a5 0x38740ab7)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

**UPDATE**

Changing

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromCtoA" sender:self];`

to

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromCtoA" sender:Nil];`

fixed it. Any ideas why?

Comment: 1. Create an exception breakpoint and look which code triggers it. 2. Post relevant code here.

Comment: Being a spaz but I couldn't find the relevant code to copy when I got to the breakpoint, sorry. I did find that changing sender to Nil fixes my error though.

Comment: Search for 'tag' in your code and you'll find the problem. 'tag' is a property on UIView but attempting to call it on a DMSScreenCViewController, possibly in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Maybe you can create an answer with the code you pasted as **UPDATE**. Do you already know whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue happened when you try to call tag property on your DMSScreenCViewController object.

This is a UIViewController subclass and there is no tag property so you cannot call it.

Maybe you try to call tag on your destination or source view controller in your segue method which is reference to DMSScreenCViewController object.

Answer (score 0):

DMSScreenCViewController Check that this is the expected class as I suspect it's not.

You may have to update a storyboard